# after converting to lowercase and hyphen, record is not gathered

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to convert all values in url to lowercase and hyphen. however when it converts to lowercase and hyphen, it does not gather the record, otherwise it gathers fine with the %20. i would like your feedback to see if the coding is correct, or is there anything else i need to do. i have checked the php and arrays and they seem fine to me.

---

`example.com/user/kate/baked/cake` > goes to the description page

---

`example.com/user/kate/baked/Lovely%20Chocolate%20Cake` > goes to the description page

---

`example.com/user/kate/baked/lovely-chocolate-cake` > this does not go to description page (this is when i use the code to convert to lowercase and hyphen)

---

**Code Below**

**HTaccess**

`RewriteRule ^user/.*[A-Z\ ] linkchange.php?l=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`

`RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/baked/([a-z.*0-9_-]+)$ cakes.php?id=$1&baked=$2`

**link change php**

`<?
    $link = $_GET['l'];
    $newlink = strtr($link," ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    header("Location: http://www.example.com". $newlink,TRUE,301); exit;
?>`

** cakes php**
`

```
<?php 
$cakesmade = array();
$cakesmade = array(
"kate" => array(
"cake" => array(
"cakeingredients" => "egg, flour"),
"Lovely Chocolate Cake" => array(
"cakeingredients" => "chocolate, eggs, flour"),
"amazing cake" => array(
"cakeingredients" => "lemons, flour")
), 
);




?>
<?php foreach($cakesmade as $id => $donecake) 
foreach($donecake as $bakedcake => $description)
 { echo "<a href='user/$id/baked/{$bakedcake}'>{$bakedcake}</a><br>";
}
?>


// this part should appear once the user and variable are set in the url
The selected cake is: <?php if(isset($bakedcake)) { echo $bakedcake; } else { echo "not set"; } ?> by <?php if(isset($id)) { echo $id; }  else { echo "not set"; } ?>`
```

thanks to **croises** so far for trying to help me figure things out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a link like this :

```
$str = example.com/user/kate/baked/Lovely%20Chocolate%20Cake
// we'll need to decode the URL like so :
$url = urldecode($str);
// then, replace lowercase and replace all spaces with dashes
$url = strtolower($url);
$url = str_replace(' ', '-', $url);
```

I guess that should do it.

Comment: thanks, this is a much easier way to convert to lowercase. is this resource intensive if say this is inside a foreach loop?

the issue that im having is that once the url is converted to lowercase, the value in the array still remains capitalised `Lovely Chocolate Cake`, i am trying to gather it eventhough the url is now in lowercase. is there a way around this? and is it resource intensive?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, of course the value in the array will not change, because we are applying strtolower on the value of the link not the array, if you want to lower case all the values of the array you can use array_map (see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) but I see that you are using the key of the associative key too, so I guess the easiest way to lower case the keys is in a loop, or you can check array_reduce function.

Comment: And speaking of resources, of course less functions means less memory use and less execution time, but we should not discuss optimization or efficiency problems when there's not a real problem, try to implement the solution and see if it's fast enough for you, if not, then start thinking about optimization. Good luck.

Comment: am i doing this correct using the array_map?
`function lowercase($donecake,$returnval) {
 strtolower($donecake);
}
foreach($cakesmade as $id => $donecake) 
foreach($donecake as $bakedcake => $description)
{
 array_map("lowercase", $returnval);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the first '/' from the rewrite rules. Next, make PHP's work a bit easier by changing the first rule.

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/baked/(.*[A-Z\ ].*)$ linkchange.php?user=$1&cake=$2} [L]
```

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/baked/([a-z.*0-9_-]+)$ cakes.php?id=$1&baked=$2
```

Your link change code then becomes:

```
<?php
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $cake = $_GET['cake'];

    $cake = urldecode($cake);
    $cake = strtr($cake," ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/user/$user/baked/$cake", TRUE, 301);
    exit;
?>
```